# ActiveAdmin uninitialized constant - can not find the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I install ActiveAdmin to my application. And register the model Order to ActiveAdmin

`ActiveAdmin.register Order do`

But I get the error `uninitialized constant Order`; it seems ActiveAdmin not found the model.

My Rails.root is 
`/home/vagrant/vag/shoppe-subao`

the models is in:

`/home/vagrant/vag/shoppe-subao/vendor/core/app/models/shoppe$ ls
order.rb`

Start the rails server and get following error

`` => Rails 4.0.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
/vagrant/shoppe-subao/vendor/core/app/models/shoppe/order
Exiting
/vagrant/shoppe-subao/app/admin/order.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Order (NameError)
        from /home/vagrant/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/active_admin-82da3c55cb61/lib/active_admin/application.rb:194:in `block in load' ``

Answer (score 1):

Add `require 'activeadmin'` to your active_admin.rb initializer